# opening an image through google drives url

Tags: android, image, drive

I am using google drive to open various pdf and .doc files through my android app in a webview all seems ok but when i try to open an image of png or jpg i get an error.

"Whoops there was a problem displaying this image."

here is a test you can run in a browser to get the same error

[image link](https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://labs.jensimmons.com/examples/images/testscreen-large.jpg)

is it even possible to open images like this or should i be using an  installed app?

Comment: did u get the shareable link from google drive

Comment: @La Same error for image which uploaded to server from gallery then showing the image using url return from server.

Comment: @Rob85 please did you find a solution for this ?